# Can i set the default page for a web-capable site added to the home screen?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, homescreen

I'm developing a mobile site, with web-capable settings for iphone.
when the site is added to the home screen, it launches from a specific page
(ie. the one the user whas on when adding to the home screen)

is it possible to set your home page (or any) as default to open with the home-screen button?
thanx!